# Plotting surface without axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, geometry-surface

I want to plot a surface without axes planes.. 
I think I'll explain better with images:

I want to get whis one:

[image: desirerd]

Instead, I'm getting this:

[image: current]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This one disables all the axes stuff:

```
ax.grid(False)
for a in (ax.w_xaxis, ax.w_yaxis, ax.w_zaxis):
    for t in a.get_ticklines()+a.get_ticklabels():
        t.set_visible(False)
    a.line.set_visible(False)
    a.pane.set_visible(False)
```

Answer (score 3):

After much beating of head against wall, I was able to come up with this:

```
ax.grid(False)
ax.w_xaxis._AXINFO['y']['color'] = (0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.0)
ax.w_xaxis._AXINFO['x']['color'] = (0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.0)
ax.w_xaxis._AXINFO['z']['color'] = (0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.0)
```

Next, i bet you'll want the ticks, ticklabels, etc, turned off.  I can't do it!

One would think that `ax.axis("off")`, `ax.xaxis.visible(False)`, `ax.xaxis.set_alpha(0.0)` would do something noticeable.

I'm using version 1.0.1 and I'm suspecting there are still a lot of bugs in the axis3d object.  It's seen a lot of changes lately.

[image]

Comment: I also tried some of the obvious stuff like `ax.axis("off")` but with no luck. Kudos for digging that deep into the API to find that, but I agree that the 3D lib is definitely lacking

Answer (score 2):

What you want is the `grid` keyword (if I understood the question correctly):

```
fig=figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111,projection="3d")
ax.plot(X,Y,Z)
ax.grid(on=False)
show()
```

It would help to see how you are setting up your plot, but at least for me messing around in `pylab`, `ax.grid(on=False)` did the trick. This turns off the grid projected onto the sides of the cube. See the mplot3d API for more details:

http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/api.html

Comment: it's not only the grid.. i mean also the gray plane that makes the bound-cube.. i'd like to render only the surface, like to render them in opengl

Comment: @nkint - Have you looked through the API yourself? I took a quick look and could not find a method that seemed to remove the gray axes planes. It would help if you (1) specified exactly what you were trying to accomplish and (2) what you've tried on your own. Additionally if you did a search of past questions, you'll find a similar question that has gone unanswered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732787/how-can-i-remove-the-axes-in-an-axes3d-class